# Upscale image before uploading to imgur

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a simple skateboard generator and users can purchase the board they make. The canvas is being uploaded to imgur through their api and then sent to a 3rd party printer. Since it's being printed I need to have a higher res image.

Was wondering if there was a way to up the res of the canvas/image before the upload to imgur is happening?

Here is a link to the repo on github: https://github.com/artosousa/newMuska

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Just a general observation, you cannot magically increase the quality of an image: If you upscale it, you will have a large, pixelated image.